# Cannot delete record using ID. Error: DML statement found null SObject at position 0

Tags: apex, dml

I am trying to delete a record using the recordID:

```
final Boolean doNotAllowPartialSuccess = true;

database.delete(recordId, doNotAllowPartialSuccess);
```

I am getting this error:

> DML statement found null SObject at position 0

It's being deleted by a `Customer Community Login User` who has **READ, CREATE, EDIT and DELETE** permissions on the object.

I know the record exists.

**Questions**

1. What am I doing wrong?
2. How can I fix it?

Comment: Could you share more of your code? It seems like your recordId variable may be null.

Comment: @BartoszŚliwiński you were right! thank you

Comment: Sure, thanks ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Seems like your `recordId` variable is null. Check if you actually populate that.